# Why does the word "school" contain an 'h'?

Tags: etymology, orthography, history, historical-change

Considering the low prevalence of words in English written with the letter combination "sch", why is the word "school" written the way it is, rather than simply "scool"?

As far as I could tell, the origin of the word is the Latin word "schola", however this appears to have developed into the High English "scol". So where and why did the 'h' come back after it was previously dropped?

Hoping any etymology experts here can help.

Comment: There is an entire "dissertation" on this in the OED.

Comment: Have you looked up the word's etymology - perhaps at http://etymonline.com ? What did you find, and what questions do you still have?

Comment: From my own perspective, I do not pronounce "school" with a simple [k], but instead an [aspirated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspirated_consonant) [k<sup>h</sup>], probably a phonotactic effect, because it comes before an open vowel [u].

Comment: Short answer from the OED: Origin: A borrowing from Latin. Etymons: Latin schola, scola. The h was there already.

Comment: Because that’s the way it’s spelled.

Comment: @Spencer English does not distinguish aspirated and non-aspirated plosives after sibilants; aspiration is not normal in that context. So if you have an aspirated k in _school_, that’s definitely idiosyncratic (I assume you also have one in _scooter_?).

Comment: @Janus It's a fairly distinctive American regional  accent. Anyway, tongue slides forward on the palate for "scooter" but backward in "school". And I realize now the "u" in "school" is not [u] but closer to [ʊ].

Comment: @Spencer: what region?

Comment: @Davo I still have a question after checking etymonline: schola --> scol --> school - why did English put the h back in after old English dropped it?

Comment: Read the answer below, please.

Answer (score 4):

#### χ Marks the Spot

When Latin borrowed Greek words containing the letters χ, φ, and θ, they were rendered as *ch, ph,* and *th*, indicating their original [aspiration](https://books.google.de/books?id=fNfebt79zdwC&pg=PT218&lpg=PT218&dq=theta%20phi%20chi%20in%20latin%20orthography&source=bl&ots=aNGHxG8AVA&sig=ACfU3U3p8W73_BwtiERJPqYmU_qP_olA9Q&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjH5oCvmpfkAhUKPFAKHQleBBcQ6AEwEHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=theta%20phi%20chi%20in%20latin%20orthography&f=false). This is still the way most folks transcribe Ancient or Koiné Greek. Thus σχολή (*schole*) becomes Latin *schola*, though [*scola*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=schola) also appears.

Old English [*scōl*](http://bosworth.ff.cuni.cz/026962) ignored this particular nicety, as did, for the most part, Middle English:

> Nu hauede þe king Aruiragus enne sune..he wes isende to Rome to leornien in [*scole*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED38906/track?counter=2&search_id=1311456).
> *Now King Arviragus had a son … he was sent to Rome to be educated in school.*

The Early English Books Online I corpus shows the current spelling emerging in the later 16th c.:

> So am I in good hope of your like affection, zeale and good vvill, for and in the erecting, and establishing of a free gramer *school* vvith in this citie … — John Hooker, *Orders Enacted for Orphans*, 1575.
>
> This concordance betwene the parent at home, and the teacher in *school* for the vertewous training vp of their litle young ones, is in verie dede, to bring them vnto Christ, … Richard Mulcaster, *The first part of the elementarie vvhich entreateth chefelie of the right writing of our English tung*, 1582.

And a spelling with no *h*, though with the double vowel, still in the late 17th:

> The greatest courage that ever yet rul'd, was baffled by fortune, tho' ne're so well scool'd, … John Playford, *The Second Book of the Pleasant Musical Companion*, 1686. EEBO
>
> 3: scool pastime for children, 5: the Countrey schoolmaster — John Newton, *The Compleat Arithmetician*, 1691. EEBO
>
> So say I, he might be better employed in teaching *scool*, or any other honest occupation, then in thus Villifying and abusing an honest people … Edward Penington, *A Modest Detection of George Keith's (miscalled) Just Vindication*, 1696.

These represent a small number of orthographic holdouts: In the EEBO I corpus, from 1640 to the end of the century, there are 9877 attestations for *school* and only 17 for *scool*. Over the first four decades of the 17th c., then, the Latin-inspired spelling supplanted the one closer to Middle English.

#### The Bigger Picture

This hardly took place in isolation. Already in the early 15th c., someone with a degree of fluency in Latin took a look at [*dette*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED11437/track?counter=1), from Old French *dete*, and realizing the word must come from Latin *debitum*, decided the English word needed a *b*, though it would never be pronounced:

> Þan my vessells of siluer...be sold and paied for my [*debtes*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED11437/track?counter=1) wher myn other gods faillen. — *Wills in Bedfordshire*, 1415.

The rage to make English words more transparent to their Latin or Greek origins gets in full swing during the English Renaissance. [*Receipt*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/receipt#etymonline_v_7373) from ME *receit*, OF *receite*, adds a *p* to bring it line with feminine past participle *recepta*. In the etymological history of [*anchor*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/anchor#etymonline_v_13403), Lat. *ancora*, however, there never was an *h*, but it got one anyway from a corrupt Latin spelling.

Perhaps most ridiculous is the bird [*ptarmigan*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/ptarmigan#etymonline_v_2802), from Gaelic *tarmachan*. The Greek word for ‘wing’ started with a *p* — think *helico-pter* or *pterodactyl*, lit. ‘wingfinger’ — thus Gaelic gets a Greek appendage in the 1680s. At least somewhere in *school*’s dark past, there was an *h* that made sense as a Greek relict.

#### Conclusion

Latin threw in a *h* when borrowing Greek words containing χ, φ, or θ to show aspiration. The *rh* in *rhythm, rhyme* and *diarrhea/diarrhoea*, however, indicates a strong trill in the original Greek, or, in the digestive disorder, an internal double rho that signaled the same thing. OE and ME — though a few ME manuscripts Latinize to *schole*— basically ignore this refinement peculiar to Latin, until for etymological reasons,  writers in the later 16th c. glue it back in.

Comment: So, "black magic" and guys thinking "just because?" :P

Comment: TLDR, English Renaissance wanted to be cool and _back to the roots_, so changed words to be more like the Latin and Greek. Blame sc(h)ool textbooks.